# if $T: V\to V$ and $ dim(KerT)+dim(ImT)=dimV $ can i say that $ KerT⊕ImT=V $

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

if V finitely generated and $T: V\to V$ and  $  dim(KerT)+dim(ImT)=dimV $
can i say that $ KerT⊕ImT=V $ 
  (mean V Direct sum of KerT and ImT )
  not matter the basis i am using?

 i know that Linear Transformation its not affected by basis we use

 but when i am using matrix it is Lean on the basis, so i am little confused.
if i trying to proof that V is Direct sum of  KerT and ImT 
lets say $dimV = n$
if i create a basis for KerT $$B_K = {\{v_1,..v_j}\}$$
so i can complete the B for V basis so $$B_V = {\{v_1,..v_j}\} ∪ {\{v_{j+1},..v_n}\} $$
using the Lineaer Transformation $$span(\{T(v_{j+1}),…,T(v_n)\})= ImT$$ 
But how can i proof that $KerT∩ImT=\{0\}$ or disprove it

Comment: $KerT+ImT=dimV$ ? Is this possible? $Ker T, Im T$ are subspaces of $V$ and $dimV$ is a just a...

Comment: sorry, i meant as the title said,  dim(KerT)+dim(ImT)=dimV, fixed in the post, thanks

Comment: What did you mean by "$span(B)= ImT$"? If $B=\{v_{j+1},\dots, v_n\},$ this is false. (Btw, please correct your misprint, replace v_j+1 with v_{j+1}.)

Comment: Why do you include the rank-nullity theorem ("$ dim(KerT)+dim(ImT)=dimV $") as an *hypothesis* in your title?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it true that if $T$ is a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ then $V=\ker T\oplus \operatorname{im}T$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861598/is-it-true-that-if-t-is-a-linear-operator-on-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space)

Comment: @Anne Bauval
 span(B)=ImT because i create B_k first as basis for KerT, so its image dont affect the span, am i wrong?

Comment: also you are right about the dim it always true, so it not necessary, this is how i tried to dectibed my question, so that why probably.

Comment: $ImT=span(\{T(v_{j+1}),\dots, T(v_n)\}),$ not $span(\{v_{j+1},\dots, v_n\}).$

Comment: @Anne Bauval oh right, this is the reason behind  dim(KerT)+dim(ImT)=dimV i missed it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false that $\operatorname{Ker} T \oplus \operatorname{Im} T = V$. In fact, if $V$ is of even dimension, you can even have $\operatorname{Ker} T = \operatorname{Im} T$, by choosing a basis $(e_1, \dots, e_{2m})$ of $V$ and taking $T(e_k) = 0$ for $k \leq m$ and $T(e_k) = e_{k - m}$ for $k \geq m+1$ and extending by linearity. (For odd dimension you can do pretty much the same for $\dim V - 1$ coordinates and then sending the last $e_k$ to $0$)

Comment: oh you say for example $T:R^4 \to R^4 $ and T(x,y,z,w)=(z,w,0,0)
So we got KerT=ImT and dim(KerT)=dim (ImT), right?

Comment: Exactly. (filler for the character limit)

Comment: I couldn't figure it out myself, you helped me a lot, thanks

Comment: Actually, the question was a duplicate.